# Executing more that one cases in switch-case MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to go to a specific part of the script based on the user input and then continue from there and execute the whole script after that. I tried implementing it using switch case, but the problem is that in switch case in matlab, there is no fall through to the next case when wee do not explicitly calling break. But my program logic is that I need to go to a case, and execute all cases after that, including that one. How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Here is my script for reference:-

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

disp('This is a script to do the back projection for an event given the required input files.');
disp('Please make sure you have copied all of the following files into the ./back_projection/data directory:-');
disp(' ');
disp('1. V_{array}.txt - File containing the velocity data of all the stations selected from the array in one single column');
disp('2. T_{array}.txt - FIle containing the corresponding time data for rall the stations selected from the array in one single column');
disp('3. P_time_{array} - File containing the P wave arrival time of the event at all all the selected stations of the array');
disp('4. stnlat_{array} - File containing the station latitudes of all the stations selected from the array');
disp('5. stnlong_{array} - File containing the station longitudes of all the stations selected from the array');
disp('6. data_info_{array}.txt - File containing the GCARC, AZ and BAZ of the event at all the stations selected from the array');
disp(' ');
input('Continue? (After making sure, press enter)','s');
clc

disp('Choose from where to start processing :-');
disp('0. Generate grid (Start from the beginning)');
disp('1. Station check');
disp('2. Cross correlation');
disp('3. Rupture back projection');
disp('4. Net stack alignment');
disp('5. Cumulative plot of energy');
disp('6. Plot of energy peaks at each second');
disp('7. Saving movie frames');
disp('8. Run a movie test');
disp('9. Stack plots for STF calculation');
disp('10. STF plot & calculation');
disp('11. Stack plots for plotting earthquake traces');
disp('12. Plot of all earthquake traces');
disp(' ');
listener=input('Enter your choice: ');
clc

switch listener
%% Starting back projection
    case 0
    delete array.txt;
    cd back_projection;
    gridgen;
    save variables/vars0;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end

    case 1
    case 2
    case 3
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    clear;
    load variables/vars0;
    o='y';

    a_arr = [];
    increment = 0;

    while(strcmpi(o,'y'))
        array = input('Enter array: ','s');
        disp(' ');
        disp('Station Check...');
        station_check;
        save variables/vars1;
        opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
        if(opts=='y')
            return
        end
        clear;
        load variables/vars1;
        increment = increment+1;
        a_arr = [a_arr;array];
        disp(' ');
        disp('Cross Correlation...');
        Crosscorrelation;
        save variables/vars2;
        opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
        if(opts=='y')
            return
        end
        clear;
        load variables/vars2;
        disp(' ');
        disp('Back Projection...')
        rupture_back_projection;
        save variables/vars3;
        opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
        if(opts=='y')
            return
        end
        clear;
        load variables/vars3;
        o = input('Do you want to enter more arrays (y/n)? ','s');

    end

    cd ..;
    fid = fopen('array.txt','w');
    for j = 1:increment
        fprintf(fid,'%s \n',a_arr(j,:));
    end
    fclose(fid);
    cd back_projection;
    %%
    case 4
    load variables/vars3;
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    disp(' ');
    disp('Aligning all the arrays...');
    net_stack_align;
    save variables/vars4;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    case 5
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    clear;
    load variables/vars4;
    %%
    input('Close the plot and press enter');
    disp(' ');
    disp('Doing a cumulative plot of the energy in the provided time window...');
    start_win = input('Enter the starting time of the window: ');
    end_win = input('Enter the closing the of the window: ');
    cumulative_plot(b_corr,e_lat,e_long,start_win,end_win,ev_lat,ev_long);
    input('Close the plot and press enter');
    save variables/vars5;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    case 6
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    clear;
    load variables/vars5;
    %%
    disp(' ');
    disp('Plotting the energy peak at all points in time (secs) within the time window...');
    end_win = input('Enter the closing time of the window (window starts from 1 second): ');
    peak_time_wise(b_corr,e_lat,e_long,end_win,ev_lat,ev_long);
    input('Close the plot and press enter');
    save variables/vars6;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    case 7
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    clear;
    load variables/vars6;

    disp(' ');
    disp('Saving movie frames ...');
    movie_slices(b_corr, e_lat, e_long, bp_l, bp_u);
    disp('Saved');
    save variables/vars7;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end

    case 8
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    clear;
    load variables/vars7;
    %%
    disp(' ');
    disp('Running a movie test');
    frameskip = input('Enter the number of frames to skip for testing: ');
    movie_test(b_corr,e_lat,e_long,bp_l,bp_u,frameskip);
    input('Close the plot and press enter');
    save variables/vars8;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end

    case 9
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    clear;
    load variables/vars8;

    %% Miscellaneous Calculations
    disp(' ');
    disp('Back Projection has been done. Starting miscellaneous calculations.');
    disp('STF calculation...');
    o='y';

    while(strcmpi(o,'y'))
        array=input('Enter the array: ','s');
        stack_plot;
        movefile(fullfile('output',['stack_uncorr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'.txt']),fullfile('output',['stack_uncorr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'_stf.txt']));
        movefile(fullfile('output',['stack_corr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'.txt']),fullfile('output',['stack_corr_',num2str(bp_l),'_',num2str(bp_u),'Hz_',array,'_stf.txt']));
        save variables/vars9;
        opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
        if(opts=='y')
            return
        end
        clear;
        load variables/vars9;
        o=input('Do you want to enter more arrays? (y/n) ','s');
    end
    case 10
    loadd variables/vars9;
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    STF_calc;
    input('Close the plot and press enter');
    save variables/vars10;
    opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
    if(opts=='y')
        return
    end
    case 11
    case 12
    path=strsplit(pwd,'\');
    pathcheck=strcmp(cell2mat(path(end)),'back_projection');
    if (pathcheck==0)
    cd back_projection;
    end
    clear;
    load variables/vars10;
    %%
    disp(' ');
    disp('Plotting earthquake traces...');
    o='y';
    while(strcmpi(o,'y'))
        array=input('Enter the array: ','s');
        stack_plot;
        trace_plot;
            save variables/vars11;
        opts=input('Do you want to quit the program? (y/n)','s');
        if(opts=='y')
            return
        end
        clear;
        load variables/vars11;
        o=input('Do you want to enter more arrays? (y/n) ','s');
    end
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% To add any additional scripts, put the scripts in the './back_projection'
% directory  and then insert the script call in this section below.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
disp(' ');
disp('Process completed');
cd ..;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred approach would be to separate your code into functions (possibly [local functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) or even [private functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html), which has the added advantage that this makes the code more readable, and then have each function such that at its end, it calls the next function in the sequence before it returns.

This will create exactly the cascade you want, and in your main script, you only need to have a switch statement which calls the appropriate function for that particular step in the 'cascade'.

E.g.:

```matlab
function main_function(Input)
  switch(Input)  % assumes appropriate Input checks and sanitization has occured
    case 1; step1_generate_grid();
    case 2; step2_station_check();
    case 3; step3_cross_correlation();
    case 4; step4_etc_etc();
    otherwise; disp('Nothing to perform');
  end
end

function step1_generate_grid()
  disp('Generating Grid...');
  step2_station_check(); % Go to next step in cascade
end

function step2_station_check()
  disp('Checking station...');
  step3_cross_correlation(); % Go to next step in cascade
end

function step3_cross_correlation()
  disp('Performing cross-correlation...');
  step4_etc_etc(); % Go to next step in cascade 
end

function step4_etc_etc()
  disp('Performing final steps etc...');
  % Final step in cascade, no further functions to call.
end
```

Comment: I was thinking of nested if else statements, but this would actually improve readability. Thanks.